# Do we have any alternative server to configure mails instead of gmail using SMTP pro Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, smtp

I am looking for this alternative server since gmail SMTP server can send only 500 mails per day. What if number of customers are more than 500 per day? How to incorporate this situation?

There by I would like to know if there exists any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SMTP Pro Mailer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html). You can set external services for sending mail, such as SendGrid or Amazon SES.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the others may be confused by your question.

I understand that you are already using the SMTP Pro Mailer by Ashley Schroder but you want to replace Gmail which is what you use now with another email provider?

I highly recommend that you take a look at [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/), which provides the first 12,000 emails for Free every single month and the price is very reasonable for anything more than that.

**UPDATE:** Mandrill no longer provides the first 12,000 emails for free. You may want to consider [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) instead.